# Obtaining permissions for a file in C

Tags: c, file-permissions, fstat

I am looking for a way to check and make sure a file is readable, writeable, and exists, and if it is not I want to print a message stating so. I believe the information I am looking for can be found using fstat(), I just don't know the correct way to get it.

If open sets a specific errno if I try to open a unreadable, unwriteable, or non-existant file with O_RDRW, I think that would be the ideal solution.

Here is what I have tried:

```
//function to open the file
int f_open(const char *filename){
   int fid;
   if ((fid = open (filename, O_RDWR)) < -1){
      return -1;
   }

   struct stat fileStat;
   if (fstat(fid, &fileStat) < 0){
      return -1;
   }

   //check write permission
   if (!S_IWUSR(fileStat.st_mode)){
      printf("Not writeable\n");
      return -1;
   }
   //check read permissions
   if (!S_IRUSR(fileStat.st_mode)){
    printf("Not readable\n");
    return -1;
   }
   return fid;
}
```

I am receiving the following error when I try and compile:

```
tester.c: In function 'f_open':
tester.c:56:14: error: called object '128' is not a function
tester.c:60:14: error: called object '256' is not a function
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to check the permissions *before* you try to open the file? Especially since you don't close the file if the checks fail.

Comment: Closing is handled in a different function. My reason for calling open first is because I need the fid to call fstat().

Comment: S_IWUSR is not a function! http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/POSIX_Reference/sys/stat.h#Member_constants

Comment: Yes, but when you return `-1` the file *can't* be close by another function.

Comment: Although that won't matter with the code you have in the question, as `open` will fail if you don't have the correct permissions. So the access checks will only happen if the file exists and you can read and write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`access`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access) for permission checking

```
int rw = access(filename, R_OK | W_OK);
if (rw == 0) {
    /* read/write granted */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The macros you are using are bit values, not functions.

```
//check write permission
if ((S_IWUSR & fileStat.st_mode) == 0){
    printf("Not writeable\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Example Here: http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:fstat

EDIT: The 'access' function indicated above is a better choice IWUSR doesnt tell you if YOU can write it, it tells you if the owner can.